# JavaScript RegExp to extract two consecutive words after a symbol

Tags: javascript, regex

There is a string that contains symbol `$`. I need to extract one or two words that go after that symbol using JS RegExp. If there is something other than a space between two words (i.e. line break or fullstop) then only the first word should be matched.

So it should be:

- *$* chararacter
- no space, a word character immediately [a-zA-Z]
- optional space
- optional word, which can be bound by fullstop or comma (but they should not be included in the match)

Even though I don't need *$* in my selection, it can be easily removed afterwards, so the goal is to extract the string containing one or two words, which go after *$*.

Comment: Show us what you've tried

Comment: This is fairly easy for a regex, why the verbose description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
var string = 'df vbdf$hello world? hehe!!'; // random string

var rgx = /\$([A-z]+[ ]?([A-z]+)?)/g;

var output = string.match(rgx);

console.log(output);
```

The `$` will be included in the output, so will be the extra space in case there's only one word, but it should give you a good start to play around with.